# Multiple URL Parameters with BizTalk WCF-WebHttp Send Port

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm working with a RESTful API within BizTalk. I need to make a POST against the following endpoint:

`http://mycompany.sb01.com/atwork/api/v5.0`

I've tested my API Url via Postman with the following(Which works):

`http://mycompany.sb01.com/atwork/api/v5.0/UID?name=bob&id=028153`

I'm having trouble converting this into a send port in my BizTalk application due to having multiple URL parameters in my POST. When I have the below binding in the BizTalk Admin Console I get a System.ArgumentException which tells me that '=' is an unexpected token and that the expected token is ';'.

```
<BtsHttpUrlMapping>
<Operation Name="ID Insert" Method="POST" Url= "/UID?name={name}&id={id}"/>
</BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

But it only ever works with 1 URL parameter, not multiple ones. If I remove:

```
&id={id}
```

from my binding, it goes through without any exceptions. How does BizTalk handle multiple URL parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape `&` in the querystring to `&amp;`

So it is

```
<BtsHttpUrlMapping>
    <Operation Name="ID Insert" Method="POST" Url= "/UID?name={name}&amp;id={id}"/>
</BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape ampersand sign(&) to `&amp;`
Url in **Operation** tag should look like this

```
Url= "/UID?name={name}&amp;id={id}"
```